# Using if statements with tkinter Events

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, events

I'm trying to create a single function that would respond differently depending on the Event that called it.  So I have this very simple UI where I removed the original Title bar and created my own one. I put a close button and a minimize button. I'm using the  and  events to trigger a method that changes the background color of the close button. I was wondering if I could use the same method with an if statement to change the background color of the other button or the only way (maybe even the better one?) would be to create another method for it.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os


# --- main ---

root = Tk()

# --- variables ---

bg  = '#2c2c2c'
width = 800
height = 500

# --- classes ---

class AvatarLoader:

    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        root.title("Avatar Loader")
        self.main.overrideredirect(True)
        self.main.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+400+200')
        self.main.resizable(width=True, height=True)

        self.title_bar = Frame(root, bg=bg, relief = 'raised', bd=1, highlightcolor = bg,             
                               highlightthickness=0, cursor = 'fleur')
        self.title_bar.pack(fill=X)

        self.title_name = Label(self.title_bar, text='Avatar Loader', bg=bg, fg='white')
        self.title_name.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.close_button = Button(self.title_bar, text='X', font=("Calibri",10,"bold"), 
                                   command=root.destroy,bg=bg, padx=4, pady=2, 
                                   activebackground="red", bd=0, fg='white', 
                                   activeforeground="white", highlightthickness=0,
                                   cursor="arrow", height=1)

        self.close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.close_button.bind('<Enter>', self.change_on_hovering)
        self.close_button.bind('<Leave>', self.return_to_normal_state)

        self.minmax_button = Button(self.title_bar, text="_", font=("Calibri",10,"bold"), 
                                    command=minimize, bg=bg, padx=4, pady=2, 
                                    activebackground="#353535", bd=0, fg='white',
                                    activeforeground="white", highlightthickness=0,
                                    cursor="arrow", height=1)
        self.minmax_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.minmax_button.bind('<Enter>', self.change_on_hovering)
        self.minmax_button.bind('<Leave>', self.return_to_normal_state)

        self.window = Canvas(root, bg=bg, highlightthickness=0, width=width, height=486)
        self.window.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)
        self.tab_open = Button(self.window, text='Open', bg="#eabb2d", fg='black', width=2,
                               height=1, padx=20, cursor="arrow", command=open_tab)
        self.tab_open.place(anchor=W, rely=0.5)

    def get_pos(event):

        global xwin
        global ywin

        xwin = event.x
        ywin = event.y

    def move_window(event):
        root.geometry(f"+{event.x_root - xwin}+{event.y_root - ywin}")

    def change_on_hovering(self, event):
        self.close_button['bg'] = 'red'

    def return_to_normal_state(self, event):
        self.close_button['bg'] = bg

    # --- variables ---

    mode_b = 1
    add_open = 0


# --- functions ---

def open_tab():
    pass

def minimize():
    pass


av = AvatarLoader(root)
av.title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', AvatarLoader.move_window)
av.title_bar.bind('<Button-1>', AvatarLoader.get_pos)
av.title_name.bind('<B1-Motion>', AvatarLoader.move_window)
av.title_name.bind('<Button-1>', AvatarLoader.get_pos)

root.mainloop()
```

So the method in question is "change_on_hovering" where I would like to say something like:
"if self.minmax_button.bind('', self.change_on_hovering) was the trigger: Then change the close_button[bg], else: change the minmax_button[bg]

Update:

I tried this:

```
self.minmax_button.bind('<Enter>', self.change_on_hovering)
self.close_button.bind('<Enter>', self.change_on_hovering)

def change_on_hovering(self, event):
    if self.close_button.bind('<Enter>', self.change_on_hovering):
        self.close_button['bg'] = 'red'
    else:
        self.minmax_button['bg'] = '#303030'
```

The result was on mouse Entering either one of these Buttons the close button's bg changed 'red'

Answer (score 0):

`event.widget` is the widget that triggers the event, so use `event.widget["bg"] = ...` inside the two functions.

```
def change_on_hovering(self, event):
    event.widget['bg'] = 'red'

def return_to_normal_state(self, event):
    event.widget['bg'] = bg
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that should happen. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @AleksK. Answer updated with sample code.

Comment: Can't get it to work. In your example, there's no "if" statement. I updated the question by adding what I tried, but it didn't work. Maybe it could serve as an example of what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: `if` is not necessary using my proposed solution.  I have tested and it works for me.